# How to stop Function from forging ahead - using setTimeout already

Tags: javascript, video, settimeout

So this one is interesting. I am using a setTimeout to delay the function in order to determine the location of a popup. The code semi-works but is forging ahead of placing the popup without the location in place (if I put in an alert, it then works, putting the popup in the right place. as soon as I take the alert out, it no longer puts it in the right place). I have added a setTimeout to buy some time to get the location down (seems to be working), but the rest of the code moves forward while the timeout is counted down.

In the below example, it is moving ahead with adding:

- trigger
- container:
- html
- content

before it gets Placement - meaning that it doesn't get placed in the right location.

Here's the code:

```
var VideoOption = {
  placement: function getPosition(context, source) {
    var position = $(source).position();
    setTimeout(function() {
      //alert(position.left);
      if (position.left < 500)
        return "right";
      if (position.top < 300)
        return "bottom,";
      return "top,";
    }, 1000)
  },
  trigger: "Manual",
  container: "html",
  html: true,
  content: '<video autoplay>' +
    '<source src="' + props.video_path + '" type="video/mp4"></source>' +
    '</video>'
};
```

So how can I make sure that Trigger, container, HTML, and content doesn't forge ahead before the "placement" gets populated? Can I add that inside the setTimeout? I have tried but isn't working.

I use the exact same code (it was coded by someone and I am re-utilizing it) and it works perfectly for small images and text so I am thinking that it takes a little longer to load the video so buying time with the setTimeout seems logical?

Thoughts?

Comment: Try adding your other stuff in the setTimeout block

Comment: You can't `return` from `setTimeout`. You could approach this in two ways, a `Promise` based approach, or a `callback` approach. You could return a `Promise` from your `getPosition` function, or you could accept a `callback` argument in the `getPosition` function.

Comment: Hi Jacob. How would you get a promise from getPosition? This seems like it may be the solution.

Comment: @brentfraser You'd need to actually return a Promise from that function yourself.

Comment: @brentfraser perhaps moving the "var position = ..." line down inside of the setTimeout will solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code runs to completion. Meaning setTimeot is not pausing your code its just saying hey when you done with rest of the code and after this amount of milliseconds pass run this function.
The `alert` function is an exception its really halting the js code until user interaction.
Anyway to solve your problem you will have to use DOM events like after `onLoad` if you use jquery you can just pass the function to $ like this `$(function(){})`
You can read more about javascript [concurency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) and about [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Events) at mdn. Hope it's been helpful.